# GORM createCriteria OR Statement with Alias

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm passing a list of IDs called `statuses` from the view to the controller. In the controller I'm simply executing:

```
def statusSelection = params.list('statuses')
```

I'm using `createCriteria` to then fetch a list of domain-class records:

```
MyDC.createCriteria().list(
    max: params.max,
    offset: params.offset,
    order: params.order,
    sort: querySort) {
        statuses { // hasMany statuses: Status
            or {
                statusSelection.each { // loop through params list
                    idEq(it.id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This has been working fine until the requirements requested the table in the view allow for sorting of the `status` property. Now I'm getting a `org.hibernate.QueryException` with the following message:

> duplicate association path: statuses

This is due to the `querySort` value I'm sure, but I don't know how to alias the sort and maintain the `or` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If when error raise querySort == "statuses" then you can create alias to replace that querySort. You should change your gsp to return statusSort instead statuses

```
MyDC.createCriteria().list(
max: params.max,
offset: params.offset,
order: params.order,
sort: querySort) {
    createAlias('statuses', 'statusSort') //This alias will replace the querySort 
    statuses { // hasMany statuses: Status
        or {
            statusSelection.each { // loop through params list
                idEq(it.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read a very interesting discussion here: [Sorting on database server or application server in n-tier architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870929/sorting-on-database-server-or-application-server-in-n-tier-architecture?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the `'in'` clause, but this works just as well. Good answer.